# SSRS Database Concept

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

If I have a Production database (SQL Server), and I install SSRS on a separate server, will SSRS intelligently query and store report data off-hours, or does it still pull data from the Production database server in real-time when reports are run in the middle of the day?

In essence, the main point is to try to avoid running data-intensive SSRS reports during the day, which slow down Production. Conceptually and ideally, there should be a nightly copy over of Production to a Prod2 database, and the reports would be run against Prod2, but I am not sure if this is what SSRS already does.  If the reports are run overnight, it shouldn't matter much either way, but it would make a difference during the day.

Comment: [Cached Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/caching-reports-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) is the only option available that I know of.

Comment: Assuming you don't need any live reports during the day time, Dales options is the only way. Alternative is to have a dedicated reporting instance with replication of the live server to report from